# PhoneGap - IOS Scroll

Tags: php, xcode, cordova

I am developing a basic application on PhoneGap with IOS guide and facing an issue when I try to run the application on Xcode. The data part does not scroll.

The meta viewport part has the following code

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
```

Any help here please ..

Answer (score 0):

You can implement scrolling in your Phonegap app using CSS, for example:

```
.scrollable {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Or use Javascript - [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) is a neat little library that takes care of it for you.